# /g attribute in combination with variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to rename some files using [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file)

This is my code

```
//variable
const oldText = "some text"
const newText = "new text"

const replace = require("replace-in-file");
const options = {
 files: "./filepath",
 from: oldText/g,
 to: newText
};
```

my question is how to use my `oldText` Variable with `/g` ?

I tried this `'/' + oldText + '/g'` but that does not work. I simply want to use a variable to rename with the `/g` (global) attribute to replace all occurrences and not just the first instance.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to construct a regex dynamically using the contents of a variable, then you would use the constructor `new RegExp(str, opt)` where you can pass it a string and the options:

```
const options = {
 files: "./filepath",
 from: new RegExp(oldText, 'g'),
 to: newText
};
```